# iOS Saving User Configuration

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nscache

I am working with an iOS app that will require the user to configure part of the app and that configuration must be saved in the event the user turns on/off a part of the app. Once the app is backgrounded, the users-configuration must be removed for security purposes.

My question is what is the best way to save primarily strings and NSIntegers temporarily and then removing them when the time comes.

```
NSUserDefaults
NSCache
```

I have looked into both and am unable to come up with any solid conclusions. Is there another way that I am missing that might be better?

Thanks!
-Brian

Comment: If you're storing them temporarily, you aren't really saving them. Just have some manager that keeps them in memory

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your settings to be available while your app is in the foreground, don't store them in `NSUserDefaults`. `NSUserDefaults` persist between app launches and are removed when the user deletes the app.

For temporary storage, consider storing key/value pairs in a simple `NSMutableDictionary`. Clear the dictionary in the application delegate's `applicationWillResignActive` method to ensure that the values are cleared when the app is moved to the background.

While an `NSCache` is a key/value store similar to a dictionary, your app will clear the `NSCache` if it receives any low memory warnings. Only store non-critical (re-creatable) data in an `NSCache`.